# Share Object Data Without Copying Transformation

Tags: linked-data

Let's say I have two objects and I want them to share the same editing data. Usually you would go the Data tab and connect them by selecting one from the drop down list. The problem is that it also copies the original object's transformations, which I don't want.

Here is an example of what it should NOT be doing. I don't want it to turn the bottle back upright. Any idea it is possible to share data without sharing transformations?

[image]

I know duplicating the bottle with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then rotating it will work. The problem is I've already duplicated **a lot** of bottles with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and moved them into place. Wouldn't want to redo all this moving work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be to not apply the transformation (don't do CTRL+A) on the source object.
The reason is that this "bakes" the transformation into object's data and causes it is transfered into linked objects too.

Comment: it seems you cannot apply transformation on multi-user objects, blender (tried on 2.78a) warns with "Cannot apply to a multi user: Object "Cylinder.002", Mesh "Cylinder", aborting"

Comment: But he could apply transformation before he linked other objects.

Comment: Okay this does indeed solve the problem, half way. What you explained does work perfectly. But I've already duplicated multiple objects and I've applied the transformations. Is there a way to somehow reverse this or is there some other method to fixing this? Or am I basically screwed and I need to delete them all and redo it all?...Also not being able to apply the transformations raises a new problem when it comes to unwrapping the UV's. Any idea how to now apply the transformations?. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Sorry to say that but I think you have to manually rotate those objects to the "unrotated" state, reset the origin and rotate it back without applying the transformation. Then you will be able to link it's mesh data to other objects without the transform data.
I don't believe there is any automatic way to determine object's initial transformation if you have already applied it (which is quite logical I think).

Comment: Okay then. Thank you for your help though. I guess I'll just never apply the transformations since it seems to cause quite a few problems later on if you need to change anything. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, linked duplicates do not inherit "object mode" transformations, only "edit mode" (ie: "editing data") ones.  So, if you wish to use the same "editing data" for another object, just select thew same "mesh data", and transform your duplicates only in object mode....

[image]

or maybe I didn't get what you mean...

Comment: You are understanding it a bit wrong. Do this: Make a duplicate of an object (using Shift+D, NOT Alt+D). Then rotate the duplicated object. Then apply the transformations to both with Ctrl+A (bare in mind this is answered above but it is still not a 100% useful method for MY problem). Then link the duplicated object to the source object. Then you will see the object rotates back to match the source object's rotation. Check my screen shots above while reading this to understand it better. Thank you for your reply though!